# How to use custom a facebook dialog, like this example

Tags: facebook, iframe, dialog, facebook-graph-api

How i can create a custom dialog like this:

[image]

I'm using iframe application with graph api/new js-api, but i cant figureout a way to reproduce this, the buttons and the title, keep the user languague.

regards.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect they are doing their own modal dialog using something like the jquery Facebox plugin at http://defunkt.io/facebox/

They also appear to be violating Facebook policy by using an unapproved ad provider (AdBrite) on a canvas page.

Comment: They are also violating policy by not letting the user edit the message that is posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var dialog = FB.Dialog.create({
content: '<div style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(109, 132, 180); font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; padding: 5px; text-align: left;">Error</div><p style="margin:10px 15px;">' + message + '</p><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242); padding: 8px; text-align: right; border-top: 1px solid rgb(198, 198, 198);height:23px;"></div>',
closeIcon: true,
onClose: function() {
    FB.Dialog.remove(dialog);
},
visible: true
});
```

See also: 
http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.Dialog

Comment: This method is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `FB.ui` method to open a dialog like this. You can find example code and more details [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui).

Comment: How i can put a "banner" inside a dialog ?

Comment: You mean the banner ad? I don't believe its possible using any Facebook API. Someone correct me if I'm wrong. It may have been added by Facebook. As for the dwarf's icon, you can check all the options for stream publishing at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments

Comment: that is not a dwarf, that is THE Dungeon Master ;-)